# Custom vertical line can not show in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I want to create recyclerview by each list item has line vertical that custom.

But I create list item then line do not show.

custom_line

line_story_view.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#EEEEEE"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/line_test" />
    <View android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_test_line" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

listitem

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="95dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout67">

        <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
            android:id="@+id/rv_profile"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            app:riv_border_color="#cacaca"
            app:riv_corner_radius="2dip"
            android:src="@drawable/plachholder"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvwTime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Loading..."
            android:textAppearance="@style/AppTheme.TextAppearance"
            android:textColor="#a3a3a3"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/rv_profile"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/rv_profile"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/rv_profile"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

        <com.example.bestiiz.component.LineStoryView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:id="@+id/line" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/relativeLayout67"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_username"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="username"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="#212121" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="•"
                    android:id="@+id/textView73"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tv_username"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_username"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tv_username"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textColor="#BDBDBD" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">
                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                    android:id="@+id/cv_profile"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    app:civ_border_color="#cacaca"
                    app:civ_border_width="0.5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/plachholder" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvwCaption"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#3b3b3b"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.3"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="caption" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

picture example

[image]

When I use in my recyclerview then It is not showing line.

Thankyou and Sorry for bad english.